# How to get Delayed job process time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Im running some backround jobs using delayed_job, and I wonder how I can retrive how long the job took to process

the information is displayed on the server, but I don't know how I can save it in order to use it in my controllers/views

```
Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ("delayed_jobs"."id" = 83) LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
  AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ("delayed_jobs"."id" = 83)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Delayed Job is deleted from your database upon completion, the simplest way to do it is to have the job itself make a record in your database when it starts, and then set the completed time in your callback when the job is completed. It's inelegant, but easy to implement with an existing system.

Comment: How would I pass the job id to the callback function? I need the delayed_job id to be in the new table I have created. The problem is that the delayed_job object is returned after I call Delayed::job.enqueue, so I can't pass something I don't yet have

Comment: your idea of timestamps around the job worked, I could add some more data that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In DJ 2.1, jobs can define before and after hooks.  You could use these to record start and finish times in a database.

```
class ParanoidNewsletterJob < NewsletterJob
  def before(job)
    record_start job
  end

  def after(job)
    record_finish job
  end
...
end
```